# Can you identify the set these white vehicle elements come from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]
We got this big box of Lego bricks, and we don't have the manuals, please help!

Answer (score 3):

I'd hazard a guess for *[3661-1 Bank & Money Transfer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3661-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*, based off your Minfig, which shows up in only one set.

[image]

[image]

Free build instructions *[here](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search?initialsearch=3661#?text=3661)* at LEGO.com if you have all the pieces to this set.